# Piggybank running total: Sum Over()

Tags: apache-pig, cumulative-sum

I am using the following pig script to calculate a running total (pig local mode)

```
  Register /home/ec2-user/pig*/bin/piggybank-0.12.0.jar ;   
 define Sum org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.int.Sum();
 define Over org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Over();
 define Stitch org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Stitch();
 A = load '/home/ec2-user/staff_data.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (id:int, name:chararray, salary:int, department:chararray);
 B = group A by department;
 C = foreach B {
     C1 = order A by salary;
     generate flatten(Stitch(C1, Over(C1.department, 'Sum(C1.salary)')));
 };
```

However, I am getting the following error

Unknown aggregate Sum(C1.salary)

Anyone any ideas?

**Edit:**

Figured the answer by myself. Here it is:

```
  Register /home/ec2-user/pig*/bin/piggybank-0.12.0.jar ;   
 define Over org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Over();
 define Stitch org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Stitch();
 A = load '/home/ec2-user/staff_data.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (id:int, name:chararray, salary:int, department:chararray);
 B = group A by department;
 C = foreach B {
     C1 = order A by salary;
     generate flatten(Stitch(C1, Over(C1.salary, 'sum(int)')));
 };
```

Comment: have you tried using SUM and OVER? instead of Sum and Over